# Irrational numbers, induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have $\sqrt[3]{2}^{2^n}$.

Can I prove that this number is irrational by showing that $3$ does not divide $2^n$?

Comment: Isn't every root of a prime number irrational?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that you know how to prove that $\root3\of2$ and $\root3\of4$ are both irrational.

Comment: As a continuation to my previous statement, since you know that the cube root of 2 is irrational, you may use a proof by contradiction to tackle the problem?

Comment: @Malcolm What sort of contradiction do you have in mind?  It's true that $x^{2^n}$ irrational implies $x$ irrational, but in general it's false that $x$ irrational implies $x^{2^n}$ irrational, which is the direction you seem to be implying.  I don't see how $2$ being prime simplifies the argument much.

Comment: @ErickWong could you give an example of $x$ irrational not implying $x^{2^n}$ irrational? (Aside from $\sqrt{2}$ and similar irrationals that become integers)

Comment: @LinusS. My statement was about *general* $x$.  Why do you discard perfectly valid examples that you've already found?

Comment: @ErickWong The OP is claiming that because 3 does not divide $2^n$, the expression stays irrational. In the case of $\sqrt{2}$, 2 does divide $2^n$. I thought (though I'm not sure) that if $2^\frac{1}{k}, k>1$ is taken to some power that is not divisible (coprime, maybe?) to $k$, then it is irrational.

Comment: @LinusS. You're quite correct, and one possible argument is that $2^m$ is not a $k$th power, which doesn't depend at all on $2^m$ being prime.  My comment was directed at Malcolm, who seemed to be claiming that it was enough to use the fact that $2^{1/3}$ is _irrational_ without more specific details about the algebraic nature of $2^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dfrac{p}{q} = 2^{\frac{2^n}{3}}, (p,q) = 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{p^3}{q^3} = 2^{2^n}\Rightarrow p^3=2^{2^n}q^3\Rightarrow 2\mid p^3\Rightarrow 2\mid p$. Now if $p = 2^k$, then $p^3 = 2^{3k} \Rightarrow q^3 = 2^{2^n-3k}$. Observe $3\nmid 2^k \Rightarrow 2^n - 3k \geq 1 \Rightarrow 2\mid q^3 \Rightarrow 2\mid q \Rightarrow (p,q) \geq 2 \neq 1$, contradiction. Thus if $p = (2r+1)2^k \Rightarrow p^3 = (2k+1)^3\cdot 2^{3k} = 2^{2^n}q^3$. Now if $2^{3k} > 2^{2n} \Rightarrow q$ is even. Thus $(p,q) \geq 2 \neq 1$, contradiction. And if $2^{3k} < 2^{2^n}$, then $(2k+1)^3$ is even, contradiction, since $2k+1$ is odd, so is its cube power. Thus $\sqrt[3]{2^{2^n}}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Can't I simply say $3 \nmid 2$ and for n=k we assume $3 \nmid 2^k$ so for n=k+1 we have $2^{k+1}=2^k2$ and $3 \nmid 2$ and $3 \nmid 2^k$ so $3 \nmid 2^{k+1}$?